# Extract substring from string in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

i need to extract `oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm` from  `oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip` and i have no clue how to start.

The condition that must be met is only `.zip` needs to be removed. If there is no `.zip` then nothing should happen to the string . How to go with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `basename` instead:

```
basename oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip .zip
```

Result:

```
oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string="oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip"
echo "${string%.zip}"
```

Output:

```
oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use sed.

```
sed 's/\.zip$//' file
```

or

```
sed 's/\.zip$//' <<< "$str"
```